# Program to Multiply Numbers Won't Actually Multiply Them

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, array, loop

I am trying to write a program which takes in a number of pairs to be multiplied, then prints out the result of each multiplication. Instead of doing this, the program just prints out the number of multiplications and the numbers, but it never does the multiplications or add the newline characters (despite me explicitly using println). In the example below I specify 2 number pairs to multiply, and then enter 3,4,7,8 (entering a NL character after each number, but spaces and commas cause the same problem).

[image: Result]

I thought my approach would work, but I believe that there is something I am doing with the serial input that is causing the code not work (although there could be some other issue). I also wonder if maybe it's because I'm running this in Tinkercad and not the real Arduino IDE. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void loop()
 {
  int numOfMults = 0;                             // number of pairs to multiply
  float *numArray;                                // pointer to beginning of array memory block
  numArray = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*50);   // dynamically allocate an array that can hold up to 50 floats 

  numOfMults = Serial.parseInt(); // take in the number of multiplications from user

  Serial.println(numOfMults);

  // take in the specified amount of numbers (2 times the num of multiplications) in format: 1,2,3...
  // then convert that into an array of floats, where every 2 indices
  // is a pair of numbers to multiply
  for (int i = 0; i < (2*numOfMults) ;i++)
    {
      numArray[i] = Serial.parseFloat();
    } 
      multNums(numOfMults,numArray);  // call function to get the product of all the numbers 

      delay(5000);                    // wait 5 seconds before starting the loop again
 }
 
void multNums(int numofNums,float nums[])
{
  float *productArray;                                 // pointer to beginning of the product array memory block
  productArray = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*25);    // dynamically allocate an array that can hold up to 25 floats (for the products)

  // multiply all the number pairs in the array, store the product in another
  for(int i=0;i<(2*numofNums);i+2)
  {
      productArray[i/2] = nums[i]*nums[i+1];         // multiply current number pair, store in the product array one index at a time 
  }
  // print the products
  for(int i=0; i < sizeof(productArray) ;i++)
  {
    Serial.println(productArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0; i < sizeof(productArray) ;i++)` are you expecting that the sizeof()  a float pointer to be equivalent to the number of elements in the referenced array ?

Comment: @6v6gt that was a good catch, but even after changing it to explicitly be the number of products my output is still not right. I also am printing out the values I'm reading into the float array and they all appear to be there before I call the multiply numbers function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

In the for loop I had to use i +=2, and not i+2.

What a dumb mistake..

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues in this code:

- In C++, you are supposed to do dynamic allocation with `new` rather
  than `malloc()`.
- If you allocate dynamic memory in a loop and forget to free it (with
  `free()`/`delete`), you will quite quickly run out of memory.
- Actually, you do not even need to do any dynamic allocation at all:
  automatic allocation is the safest way to handle these arrays.
- Since you know the exact size you need, allocate that rather than a
  default size.
- `multNums` receives as a parameter the number of multiplications, not
  the length of the array.
- `i+2` does not change the value of `i`. You meant `i+=2`.
- `sizeof(productArray)` does not give the length of the array, but its
  size in bytes. Besides, your last loop is supposed to iterate only
  through the initialized part of the array.

If you fix those issues, the program should work as expected.

Comment: fixing all those things made the program work, the biggest problem was using i+2 instead of +=. And I will go back and do dynamic memory allocation in a better way or just get rid of it. I actually thought arduino was C (not c++), which is why i used malloc. New is much better.